# Hello all, I have been getting this error since I am trying to turn on my raspberry pi

Tags: boot, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNX5h.jpg)

Please advise on what to do

Comment: Normally I'd boot *live* media & run `fsck` (file-system checks) from there, but on a raspberry pi (*I don't know what media you're booting from, it maybe easier on the pi*) I'd likely remove the media & perform the `fsck` or file-system checks on another box.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, but the SD card is not even getting formatted on a windows pc, fsck command gives me another error

Comment: The SD card maybe needs replacing... They are a *consumable* media, ie. built to cost and not durability (*especially if contents are changed frequently*) so write your backup image to a new SD & use that instead.